# Скроллинг 1 экрана

Tags: css, прокрутка

подскажите пожалуйста как выполнить функцию скроллинга 1 экрана (верха) с классом .header ко второму с классом .content а дальше уже идет обычный скроллинг, нужно как вверх так и вниз скроллинг.
Без кликов и прочего, обычный скролл мышкой.

Comment: Нашел пример где такое реализовано http://ruya.ae/work/al-erkyah-city/

Comment: уточни, у тебя всегда высота хедере = высота одного экрана?

Comment: да, высота 100vh

Answer (score 2):

Добрые день, вот примерное решение.

1. получили высоту хедера
2. определили сторону в которую скролим
3. если мы находимся в хедере, доскролили до крайней точки
4. отключили "доскролл" на время анимации

```js
let nHeight = $('.header').height(),
    lastScrollTop = 0;

$(document).on('scroll', addScroll);

function addScroll() {
    let scroll = $(document).scrollTop();

    let st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;


    if (!$('body').is('.disabled')) {
        if (st > lastScrollTop && scroll < nHeight ) {
            // downscroll code
            $('body').addClass('disabled');
            $('body, html').animate({scrollTop: nHeight }, 600, function () {
                $('body').removeClass('disabled');
            });
        } else if (st < lastScrollTop && scroll < nHeight ) {
            // upscroll code
            $('body').addClass('disabled');
            $('body, html').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 600, function () {
                $('body').removeClass('disabled');
            });
        }
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
#target {
 border: 5px solid orange;
  height: 600px;
}

.gallery__grid-item {
  background: #000;
}

.gallery__grid-item:nth-child(2) {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}

.gallery__grid-item:nth-child(odd) {

}
.header {
  height : 100vh;
   border:5px solid red;
}
.footer {
    height : 600px;
     border:5px solid red;
}
.bg {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='header'>header</div>
<div id='target' >
  
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Comment: Эммм, у меня почему то не работает. В консоли пишет Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'postion' has already been declared

Comment: Поправил ответ, очевидно у вас просто дублируются let postion

Comment: дружище спасибо, теперь отлично, НО скролл не отключается во время анимации, и получается при скроле трясет, можно это как то поправить?