# Добавление класса при достижении div блока

Tags: jquery, прокрутка

Добрый день.
Пожалуйста, подскажите а то уже 3 дня мучаюсь не как не получается.
В общем - есть допустим верх

```
<div class="header"></div>
```

и есть центральный div например

```
<div class="content"></div>
```

и есть футер к примеру

```
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Что необходимо - при достижении при прокрутке блока с классом content к тегу html добавляется класс например active и удалялся при покидании этого класса content

находил решения но они работают только если скроллишь вверх, а если вниз класс остается на месте.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь.Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добрый день. что нужно сделать

1. Определить координаты контента
2. Определить высоту элемента
3. Повесить обработчик на скролл, который проверяет координаты скролла документа
4. Написать условие , которое добавляет класс к body

```js
var postion = $('#target').offset().top,
    height = $('#target').height();
$(document).on('scroll', function (){
  var scroll = $(document).scrollTop();
  if(scroll  > postion && scroll < (postion + height) ) {
     $('body').addClass('bg')
     }else {
        $('body').removeClass('bg')
     }
})
```

```css
#target {
 border: 5px solid orange;
  height: 600px;
}

.gallery__grid-item {
  background: #000;
}

.gallery__grid-item:nth-child(2) {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}

.gallery__grid-item:nth-child(odd) {

}
.header {
  height : 600px;
   border:5px solid red;
}
.footer {
    height : 600px;
     border:5px solid red;
}
.bg {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='header'>header</div>
<div id='target'>
  
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, то что нужно, НО, еще бы сделать что бы добавлялся класс как только я полностью буду на контенте #target, очень буду вам благодарен

Comment: вот когда скроллишь снизу вверху в идеале получается, а когда наоборот то лучше бы когда полностью

Comment: Исправил ответ.

Comment: ой отлично) спасибо огромное))

Comment: Если ответ, подошел можете нажать V

Comment: showBro, дружище может вы мне и с этим поможете, я вообще буду прыгать от радости)) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/792554/Скроллинг-1-экрана